# Still having trouble with embedding an MP4 into shiny

Tags: r, shiny, mp4

I have followed previous posts regarding embedding MP4 files into Shiny.

Here is what I have:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  tags$video(id="video2", type = "video/mp4",src = "slide1a.mp4",controls = "controls")
  
    
)
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
}
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have the file "slide4a.mp4" in the www folder.

When I run it, the controls appear but nothing else.

Any help much appreciated.

Sincerely,
Erin

Comment: You've got "slide1a.mp4" in the code but "slide4a.mp4" in the description. Is one of these wrong?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  Please verify the mp4 filename.

Comment: Yes, it should be slide1a.mp4

Comment: This is odd.  When I run the app from Rstudio, it doesn't work.  However, if I run it from R, it's fine.  Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: For what it's worth:  once I deployed this to shinyio.apps, it worked fine.

Comment: FWIW, this only works for me when I run the app in RStudio and then select "Open in Browser". (Note: it does not work within RStudio.) It doesn't work when I run the app from the command line ("Script app.R"). Interestingly, when I inspect the source HTML for the page that works and the page that doesn't work, it's exactly the same. It must be a path issue.